# How to read only until spesific character of each last value row in CSV files from PHP

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have file of csv that contains data like this :

```
> NO|NAME|NUMBER
> 1|Ryan|998877
> 2|Good|998899
> 3|Bright|997788
> 4|Tedd|998866
```

I want to read just number of each row (99xxxx), but the data (.csv) not formatted it as a column (comma separated) so I dont know how to take out just the number I'm using php to read the csv files, please help. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

[fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) allows you to specify an alternative delimeter:

```
$row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, '|');
$number = $row[2];
```